# INSERT INTO another table FROM another select doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Cannot work with this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (
    id_member_card
    ,points
    )
VALUES 
    (
        SELECT idMemberCard
        ,punti FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT idMemberCard
                ,SUM(amountOriginal) AS speso
                ,SUM(amountFinal) AS punti
            FROM transactions
            WHERE date_transaction_UTC BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                    AND '2018-03-19 23:59:59'
            GROUP BY idMemberCard
            ) AS derived
        WHERE speso >= 50
        ) AS d2
    )
```

The error is

> Syntax error near 'SELECT idMemberCard , punti FROM (SELECT * FROM ( SELECT idMemberCard , SUM(amou' at line 6

Where am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: Remove `Values ( )` keep the SELECT inside that though. `Values()` is for specifying a list, but you don't have a list, you have a result set, so just `INSERT INTO <table> SELECT....`

Answer (score 4):

No `VALUES` is needed for `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (id_member_card , points) 
    SELECT idMemberCard , punti
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT idMemberCard , SUM(amountOriginal) AS speso, 
                       SUM(amountFinal) AS punti
                FROM transactions
                WHERE date_transaction_UTC BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-19 23:59:59'
                GROUP BY idMemberCard
              ) AS derived
          WHERE speso >= 50
         ) t2;
```

You can greatly simplify the logic to:

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (id_member_card , points) 
    SELECT idMemberCard , SUM(amountOriginal) AS speso, SUM(amountFinal) AS punti
    FROM transactions
    WHERE date_transaction_UTC >= '2018-01-01' AND 
          date_transaction_UTC < '2018-03-20'
    GROUP BY idMemberCard
    HAVING speso >= 50;
```

You could also specify this as a view if you didn't want to actually store the values in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly express this as :

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (id_member_card , points) 
SELECT idMemberCard , punti 
FROM (SELECT * FROM 
             ( SELECT idMemberCard , SUM(amountOriginal) AS speso,     
                      SUM(amountFinal) AS punti 
               FROM transactions
               WHERE date_transaction_UTC BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-19 23:59:59'
               GROUP BY idMemberCard ) AS derived
WHERE speso >= 50
```

However, your core logic would be rewrite as :

```
INSERT INTO final_tab (id_member_card , points) 
SELECT idMemberCard ,  SUM(amountFinal) AS punti,
       SUM(amountOriginal) AS speso,     
FROM transactions
WHERE date_transaction_UTC BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-19 23:59:59'
GROUP BY idMemberCard
HAVING speso > 50;
```